# How to get the List of AWS Services which I am using in my AWS Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to get a list of Active AWS Services which I am using in my AWS Account.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2):

The simple method I use is just to go into the Billing service and then into the Bills. You select the actual month and You should see all the charges for the services You use. 0$ means that Yo've used the service in the past.
Example:
[image]